# How to create a Elasticsearch test environment to run my capybara tests (rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, capybara

**My scenario**

I have a rails app that uses elasticsearch to index some data.

For my unit and integrations automated tests I just mock elasticsearch using FakeWeb but now I want to write some acceptance tests and I would like to use elasticsearch without mocking it.

**My question**

How can I run 2 clusters of elasticsearch (one for my development environment and one for my test environment), I don't want the clusters to share any data. I am also trying to find a way to say "in my capybara tests I want to use this cluster"

PS: The clusters have to be in the same machine (localhost)

**What I've tried**

- Run another instance of elasticsearch in a different port: I doesn't work because elasticsearch will somehow share data with this new instance
- Copy & paste elasticsearch folder, change the configs `config/elasticsearch.yml`: I changed the `cluster_name` and ran two instances of elasticsearch, one for each folder but they somehow share data.

Any tips or solutions will be helpful.

Comment: What OS are you running? If you are running on Linux, then I would suggest using [Docker](https://www.docker.io/) for this. If you are running Mac OS X or Windows, then you can setup a VM to host Docker, or use [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) directly with [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/). Combining these with build tool plugins (e.g., [Gradle Vagrant Plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-vagrant-plugin)) can be quite useful, and they give stable test environments for smoke tests, functional tests and acceptance testing.

Comment: Hitting on a different issue, you could paste your altered `elasticsearch.yml` so that we can figure out why it's not actually changing the cluster.

Comment: @pickypg, I am running Mac OS X so the VM solution might work but I think it's not a smooth process to run a VM every time I need to run my suite of acceptance tests.

The only thing that I changed in my elasticsearch.yml was this line:
cluster.name: elasticsearch (one was elasticsearch and the other one was elasticsearch_test)

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Pedro_Moreira_Mamede Are you setting the clusterName on the `Client` that you are using to connect to the clusters?

Comment: @pickypg My 'real client' is my rails app but I am doing all my tests using the chrome plugin as client and I only have to set the host(IP) where my elasticsearch instance will be and the port that my instance will be listening to

Answer (score 5):

I've been using `Elasticsearch::Test::Cluster` with pretty good success.  I've setup rspec to simply start up the cluster at the beginning of any test that requires ES, then tear it down on exit.  It adds a bit of time to the testing, but then I never have to think about starting up a clean ES instance during testing.

This does *not* clean the instance in between specs so if you need more specific tests around data that is indexed, you may need to build some kind of cleanup steps, but this has worked well for me.  Both for unit tests and integration tests (with `cucumber`).

in `spec/support/test_es_server.rb`

```
require 'elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster'
class TestEsServer
  def self.cluster
    Elasticsearch::Extensions::Test::Cluster
  end

  def self.port
    @port ||= URI.parse(Rails.application.config.elasticsearch_url).port
  end

  def self.running?
    cluster.running?(port: self.port)
  end

  def self.start
    if !running?
      puts "Starting elasticsearch cluster on port #{port}"
      cluster.start(port: port, nodes: 1) unless running?
    end
  end

  def self.stop
    puts "Tearing down elastic search cluster on port #{port} if necessary"
    cluster.stop(port: port) if running?
  end
end
```

in `spec/support/elasticsearch.rb`

```
require_relative "./test_es_server"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:example, elasticsearch: true) do
    begin
      TestEsServer.start
    rescue Exception => ex
      puts "Failed to start Elasticsearch: #{ex}"
    end
  end
end

at_exit do
  begin
    TestEsServer.stop
  rescue Exception => ex
    puts "Failed to stop Elasticsearch: #{ex}"
  end
end
```

in `spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb`

```
describe MyController, elasticsearch: true do

   ... specs that require elastic search calls go here ...

end
```